# Receiving Form data fetched by FormSubmit

Tags: html, forms, post, form-submit, contact-form

l am Using Formsubmit to handle forms on my websites but l don't want want users to leave the page (being redirected) to submit. l hosted the site on netlify and tried to test the forms but i didn't the info on my email. l dont know if the forms are working or not. could there be an option of getting the forms work.
the website was a template.

i expected to find the filled info on my email, l created and activated the FormSubmit Account but they all seem not to work. i wrote to them in the sponsor box and they returned the info i had sent them in my inbox. they claim its a free service theirs no fee any way but i dont know why mine isn't working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <form action="https://formsubmit.co/d@.com" method="POST">  <input type="text"  required placeholder="FirstName" > <select class="form@>
                                        <option selected>Edu*</option>
                                        <option value="1">C</option>
                                        <option value="2">D</option>
                                        <option value="3">D</option>
                                        <option value="4">M</option
                                    </select></form>

Answer (score 0):

for forms to work there has to be a name="" on every field.
You can use FormSubmit, Formspree or FormCarry to handle your forms